# MS Teams: send message to private chat programmatically

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I try to find a way to send a private message in MS Teams' personal chattings.

I know that in 'channel > connector', I can use a webhook to achieve this.
Unfortunately, I can not find anything like that in personal chattings.

The only thing related I find is MS Graph API, but it's not what I looking for.

[image]

Currently, I am trying to use emailing API as the alternative

[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: can you explain why Graph is not acceptable, as it allows you to do this.

Comment: @HiltonGiesenow In 'channel > posts', I can use the connector(webhook) to send a message. However, in private(personal) chat, I can not find anything like that. Or, should I add an APP for that chat (bot, for example) to do this?

Answer (score 6):

A webhook / connector is one option, but it's limited to team channels, as you've noted. To send messages in a private (1-1) or group chat, you can use either a bot or the Graph. It depends if you want to send *to* others, but *from* an application (like is it ok for the users to get a message from a "bot"?) or if you want to send *as if* it came from you.

for option 1 (from a bot) you will want to look at ["Pro-active messaging"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages?tabs=dotnet) (I've also got some answers here on Stack Overflow that you can search for, under my profile).

for option 2 ("as if" the messages came from you), use the Microsoft Graph, something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http .